# How to add both Geth ang Ganache to metamask?

Tags: metamask, ganache, geth-debugging

I have been facing an issue. I want to connect Both Geth and Ganache (GUI) to Metamask one at a time for testing smart contract. But in Metamask it's already showing a network localhost RPC endpoint 8545 with chain id 1337, which is of Gnache's. Now I don't know what should be the custom RPC endpoint, chain id of Geth so that I can connect it to Metamask. Even if I change Ganache to RPC endpoint 7545 with chain id 1337 and keep RPC endpoint 8545 for Geth, but I don't know what should be the chain id for Geth which is needed for Metamask.